# How to properly link 16 and 32 bit .o files?

Tags: c, makefile, x86, ld, osdev

I switched my computer recently and since then, my makefile chain spits out a 512 byte binary with only 0x00s or the bootloader, but without everything else. I created the following as MRE:

boot.asm:

```
BITS 16
SECTION boot
GLOBAL _entry
EXTERN _start

_entry:
mov [disk],dl
mov ah, 0x2 ; read sectors
mov al, 6   ; amount = 6
mov ch, 0   ; zylinder = 0
mov cl, 2   ; first sector to read = 2
mov dh, 0   ; head = 0 (up)
mov dl, [disk]  ; disk
mov bx, _start  ; segment:offset address
int 0x13

cli
lgdt [GDT_POINTER]

mov eax, cr0
or al, 1
mov cr0, eax

mov ax, DATA_SEGMENT
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov fs, ax
mov gs, ax
mov ss, ax
jmp CODE_SEGMENT:_start

disk: DB 0x00

GDT_POINTER:
DW GDT_EXIT - GDT_ENTRY
DD GDT_ENTRY

CODE_SEGMENT EQU GDT_CODE - GDT_ENTRY
DATA_SEGMENT EQU GDT_DATA - GDT_ENTRY

GDT_ENTRY:
DQ 0x00

GDT_CODE:
DW 0xffff
DW 0x0000
DB 0x00
DB 0x9a
DB 0xcf
DB 0x00
    
GDT_DATA:
DW 0xffff
DW 0x0000
DB 0x00
DB 0x92
DB 0xcf
DB 0x00

GDT_EXIT:

TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) DB 0x00
DW 0xAA55
```

kernel.c:

```c
int _main() {
    while(1) {}
}
```

linker16.ld:

```
ENTRY(_entry);
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386);
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;

    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        *(boot)
        *(.text)
    }
    
    .data :
    {
        *(.bss);
        *(.bss*);
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata*);
        *(COMMON);
    }  
    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.note*);
        *(.iplt*);
        *(.igot*);
        *(.rel*);
        *(.comment);  
    }
}
```

linker32.ld:

```
ENTRY(_main);
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386);
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7E00;

    .text : AT(0x7E00)
    {
        *(.text)
    }
    
    .data :
    {
        *(.bss);
        *(.bss*);
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata*);
        *(COMMON);
    }  
    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        *(.note*);
        *(.iplt*);
        *(.igot*);
        *(.rel*);
        *(.comment);  
    }
}
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    nasm -O32 -f elf -o boot.o boot.asm
    gcc -m32 -c -g -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc -Wall -Werror -o kernel.o kernel.c
    ld -static -nostdlib -build-id=none -relocatable -T linker16.ld -o boot.elf boot.o
    ld -static -nostdlib -build-id=none -relocatable -T linker32.ld -o kernel.elf kernel.o
    objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin
    objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin
    cat boot.bin kernel.bin > sys.bin~
    rm *.o
    rm *.elf
    rm *.bin
    cat sys.bin~ > sys.bin
    rm sys.bin~
    qemu-system-i386 sys.bin
    
    
qemu:
    qemu-system-i386 sys.bin
```

The expected output is a blank screen, with a GDT set a few bytes after 0x7C00 when looked into compat monitor ("info registers" output). Instead it is stuck in a bootloop, since the bootloader is correctly compiled but everything after it (the while loop) is missing. Until the .o file, everything is as expected but the .elf and .bin are too short. Does someone have a solution? The versions i use are:

NASM version 2.14.02 
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 
GNU ld & objcopy (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34

EDIT:
The updated code instead produces a mess of zeros, 60 times the size it should be. The magic number is placed correctly but the kernel part is still unusable.

EDIT 2:
I found out by trial and error that removing the -relocatable argument for the linker clears out most of the zeros, yet it still doesn't work as expected and sticks in a bootloop.

EDIT 3:
If anyone gets the same problem as i did, i want the code to actually work. In the above code i fixed the GDT, since i made a mistake in it. I narrowed all DBs down to DD, but forgot that little endian reverses all bytes in it, therefore the used bit in all GDT descriptors was set to zero, making the jump impossible. In combination with fuz's answer, it is possible to get this nightmare running now.

Comment: Who told you you could `cat` two .o files to make a bigger .o file? And do you know the difference between >> and > in shell script?

Comment: The cat x.o y.o >> z.o is used in all five sources i downloaded from multiple open source OSes i learned from and also used in a few tutorials. Also i used it since i started the project about two years ago and it worked perfectly until about a week ago. That should (at least in theory) not cause the issue.

Comment: well, I'm really skeptical about catting .o files together. And really really skeptical about the giant .o file that adds more data to the end every time you build and never deletes any of it. Did you try just giving both .o files to the linker?

Comment: And no i don't actually know the difference it makes in a makefile but i just tried it with the MRE and it produced the exact same output. Is that a bug/random?

Comment: Oh in the mre i forgot to place the part that deletes all .o and .elf files after building the bin. Usually the stacking doesnt happen.

Comment: I just tried giving both files un-cat-ted and it produced a 32,3 kB binary with a TON of NULs and the 0x55AA is at the wrong place. wtf? (to be exact the 0x55AA is at 0x7DFE)

Comment: I noticed your linker script tells the linker to output an ELF file, which is a file with extra information saying which parts of the file go to which memory addresses, so the order of the things in the file doesn't really matter.

Comment: by the way I added the osdev tag since this is about operating system development. And removed a tag to make room.

Comment: @Raphael-MdN That catenation step is often done, yes, but it's done after linking and `objcopy`, not before.  It doesn't make any sense at all to catenate object files.  If you don't understand what this step does, then step back and try to understand what it does first.

Comment: Would it do any good to just tell the linker to output me a binary directly? (i did it as a workaround for an error about relocating relocatable stuff from elf32-i386 to elf32-i386 is not supported) I try to get the real error again it was before a quater year or so)

Comment: @Raphael-MdN That would do the same as linking and then using `objcopy`.  The real problem is that you catenate object files.  That cannot and will not work.  Instead, you must link kernel and bootloader separately, convert them to binary images and then catenate these images.

Comment: @fuz What would you propose to do instead? Is there an error in the linker sctipt, since if i do the cat step first, i get less data than expected, if i do it afterwards (in the MRE not at all) and instead give the linker the separate files, i get over 60 times as much data. Both don't seem to do the job right. Also i use it because in the original project i can give the linker three files separate instead of hundreds of object files originating from the library.

Comment: @fuz I'll try it, wait a second.

Comment: @fuz Unfortunately, i get the exact same result as if i gave the linker both files separately. 32,3 kB and the 0x55AA at 0x7DFE.

Comment: @Raphael-MdN The effect of `cat` first is that the second object file (`kernel.o`) is completely ignored.  And again: I said link them separately (each with their own `ld` calls, each with their own appropriate linker scripts), not pass them both to the linker.

Comment: I just saw a really huge problem with the new code: how is the first binary supposed to know where _start s address is? In the old approach, it was clear due to both o files being catted (idk why this even worked before?) but in the new one i need absolute addresses. I'll try fix that one.

Comment: @Raphael-MdN The problem with your kernel is that the compiler adds a bunch more sections you don't want.  Use `objdump -sd` on `kernel.elf` to see what sections there are.  Add all sections you don't want in the kernel to `/DISCARD/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's quite a bit strange stuff going on with your program, so instead of trying to fix this, I'll go ahead and start from scratch with something correct.

Your bootloader is mostly fine.  As you already noticed, you cannot reference symbols from your kernel in your bootloader.  The default solution is to just jump to a known location in your kernel (e.g. the beginning) and arrange things for the kernel to have its entry point there.  So we change `boot.asm` and remove `EXTERN _start`, replacing it with

```
_start  EQU 0x7e00
```

To have the kernel reliably be enterable at `0x7e00`, there is a trick.  In the linker script, we put the following lines into the beginning of the `.text` section in `linker32.ld`:

```
.text : AT(0x7E00)
{
    _start = .;
    BYTE(0xE9);
    LONG(_main - _start - 5);
```

This makes `.text` begin with a `JMP` instruction that jumps to `_main`, which is exactly what we want.

Next is the issue of random junk being appended to the kernel.  This is because you don't discard enough crap.  The easiest way is to just discard everything (i.e. `*(*)`) and explicitly list the sections you want to keep.  You need to be careful though; the compiler may decide to put extra junk into weird sections that is needed to keep the kernel working.  Alternatively, accept that the compiler does whatever it wants and eat up the larger kernel size.  The final linker script `linker32.ld` is this:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386);
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7E00;

    .text : AT(0x7E00)
    {
        _start = .;
        BYTE(0xE9);
        LONG(_main - _start - 5);
        *(.text);
        *(.text.*);
    }
    
    .data :
    {
        *(.bss);
        *(.bss*);
        *(.data);
        *(.rodata*);
        *(COMMON);
    }  
    /DISCARD/ :
    {
    *(*);
    }
}
```

You can fix the discarded sections similarly in `linker16.ld`.

Next is the build script.  I'll not discuss this in detail, but you can check the changes I made yourself.  The two important ones are (a) removing `-relocatable` (this is absolutely not what you want) and (b) adding `-fno-pic -no-pie` so the compiler doesn't get any weird ideas.

```
all:
    nasm -f elf32 boot.asm
    gcc -m32 -c -g -fno-pic -no-pie -ffreestanding -nostdlib -nostdinc -Wall -Werror -o kernel.o kernel.c
    ld -static -nostdlib -build-id=none -T linker16.ld -o boot.elf boot.o
    ld -static -nostdlib -build-id=none -T linker32.ld -o kernel.elf kernel.o
    objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin
    objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin
    cat boot.bin kernel.bin > sys.bin
    qemu-system-i386 sys.bin

qemu:
    qemu-system-i386 sys.bin
```

It should work like this, assuming the boot loader is correct (I don't have QEMU on this computer).

Comment: I know one is asked not to place a thanks comment, but Thank you so much, this answer is really great and far better then what i usually get. I have no idea why the -fno-pic -no-pie was not there but i had it in some earlier version but it's now missing in both the example and the original.

Answer (score 3):

There really isn't any such thing as a 16-bit ELF executable or object. 16-bit code is contained inside a 32-bit or 64-bit ELF object and the LD linker has support for relocations specific to 16-bit code.

It is possible for you to generate a program like `kernel.elf` and use the symbols when linking another program together. The LD linker has the option `-R` for this purpose:

> ```
>    -R filename
>    --just-symbols=filename
>        Read symbol names and their addresses from filename, but do not
>        relocate it or include it in the output.  This allows your output
>        file to refer symbolically to absolute locations of memory defined
>        in other programs. You may use this option more than once.
> ```

Assuming you assembled `kernel.asm` and linked to `kernel.elf`, you can build `boot.elf` from `boot.o` by using the symbols from `kernel.elf` like this:

```
ld -static -nostdlib -build-id=none -T linker32.ld -o kernel.elf kernel.o
ld -static -nostdlib -build-id=none -T linker16.ld -R kernel.elf -o boot.elf boot.o
```

In `boot.asm` you would be able to reference symbols in `kernel.elf` like `_main` just by putting `extern _main` on the assembly file `boot.asm`

Comment: Oh, the `-R` feature!  Totally forgot about that.

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to `cat` the 16 and 32 bit binaries together not the `.o` files. The idea is the 32 bit binary starts in memory right after the end of the 16 bit binary; so you arrange for the 16 bit binary to know its length and find the 32 bit binary.

One technique is scanning for the start of the 32 bit binary starting from the last byte of the 16 bit data region. The 16 bit trailer probably won't contain the 32 bit header, and this will be reliable on build so you know if the technique works or not the first time you try to boot the result.

NOTE: while this answer isn't wrong; I suspect that fuz will be placing a better answer shortly.

Comment: To summarize the discussion in the comments above, if i link both files separately, then objcopy the elfs to bin and then cat the bins, i am left with a mess of almost 30kB of 0x00 junk and the bios magic number at 0x7DFE. I have no clue what causes all of those zeros but the output is even more messed up because with the catinated o files i at least have a working bootloader remaining, in the second case i have 16 and 32 bit code mixed with tons of zeros. Could you please provide an alternative linker and/or makefile that produces the expected output of my example?

Comment: @Raphael-MdN I can help you debug this, but to do so, I need to see the exact code and comments you use for this updated approach.

Comment: @fuz I will edit the code above accordingly, thanks ^^